# SQL How to transform ROWS to COLUMNS and COLUMNS TO ROWS? db2

Tags: sql, db2, rows

I have an SQL query which works fine in DB2
My result is

```
SERVICE   IN   OUT   INPROGRESS

ADSL      1     5      10
VOIP      15    12     11
IPTV      20    14     17
```

Now I want to transform it to be like this:

```
CLASS       ADSL   VOIP   IPTV

IN           1     5      10
OUT          15    12     11
INPROGRESS   20    14     17
```

Although it seems long my SQL is very simple but I never had transformed this. If someone knows I will be thankful.

My SQL is

```
select  distinct 'ADSL' as SERVICE,

(select count(*) as In from ticket 
where 
(class='C1'  and
(servicesinfault='25'))),

(select count(*) as Out from ticket
where 
(class='C2' and
(servicesinfault='25'))),


(select count(*) as In_progress from ticket
where 
(class='C3' and
(servicesinfault='25')))

from ticket where servicesinfault = '25'

union all

select  distinct 'VoIP',

(select count(*) from ticket 
where
(class='C1'  and
(servicesinfault='26'))),

(select count(*) from ticket
where
(class='C2'  and
(servicesinfault='26'))),


(select count(*) from ticket
where 
(class='C3'  and
(servicesinfault='26')))

from ticket where servicesinfault = '26'

union all

select  distinct 'IPTV',

(select count(*) from ticket 

where 
(class='C1'  and
(ticket.servicesinfault='27'))),

(select count(*) from ticket
where 
(class='C2'  and
(servicesinfault='27'))),

(select count(*) from ticket
where 
(class='C3'  and
(servicesinfault='27')))

from ticket where servicesinfault = '27'
```

Comment: Which RBDMS (SQL-Server, Oracle, Mysql etc.)? There are many duplicates of this question for most of them.

Comment: There isn't a DB2 Pivot equivalent that I know, I'd suggest taking the approach suggested in the link in Ben's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a remark, your result should like:

```
CLASS       ADSL   VOIP   IPTV

IN           1     15     20
OUT          5     12     14
INPROGRESS   10    11     17
```

The pivoted version should be something like:

```
select distinct 'In' as CLASS,

                (select count(*) as 'ADSL'
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C1' and (servicesinfault = '25'))),

                (select count(*) as 'VoIP'
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C1' and (servicesinfault = '26'))),

                (select count(*) as 'IPTV'
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C1' and (servicesinfault = '27')))

  from ticket
 where class = 'C1'

union all

select distinct 'Out',

                (select count(*)
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C2' and (servicesinfault = '25'))),

                (select count(*)
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C2' and (servicesinfault = '26'))),

                (select count(*)
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C2' and (servicesinfault = '27')))

  from ticket
 where class = 'C2'

union all

select distinct 'InProgress',

                (select count(*)
                   from ticket

                  where (class = 'C3' and (ticket.servicesinfault = '25'))),

                (select count(*)
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C3' and (servicesinfault = '26'))),

                (select count(*)
                   from ticket
                  where (class = 'C3' and (servicesinfault = '27')))

  from ticket
 where class = 'C3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "PIVOT".

If your DBMS doesn't offer one, you can use the "poor man's pivot".

Look at usr's answer on this question:

[Poor Man's SQL Pivot. List Questions as Columns and Answers per User in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924641/poor-mans-sql-pivot-list-questions-as-columns-and-answers-per-user-in-one-row)

Comment: @Dejan Take a look at the link which offers a way without using `PIVOT`. He posted it before you clarified which RBDMS you were using ;-)

Comment: @Dejan, not last time I checked, but the latest version may.