# Table Manipulation in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

I am using DB2 and have the following table (Table A - 3 Columns) :

```
EmpNum  YearMonth    Value

100     201201      2
100     201207      1
100     201206      7
102     201201      8
102     201205      15
102     201207      4
```

… etc

I would like to produce a new Table B with one row per employee, and a column for each YearMonth.

I am hoping that I can generate the Table B 'YearMonth' column name dynamically from the data as there will be 120 columns.

The value would then be put in the cell with the associated YearMonth heading to give a table like this :

```
EmpNum  201201  201202  201203  201204  201205 201206 201207 etc ….

100         2                                   7       1
102         8                            15             4
```

I have tried looking up 'Stored Procedures' and 'Dynamic Column Names' but cannot fine anything quite like this.

I have two questions :

1. Is this possible in DB2 ?
2. What should I look up for more information ?

Thanks in anticipation !

Ross

Comment: Is there a reason why you are going *against* normalization ?

Comment: The original data is normalized. In  expected query result will probably not be stored. So I don't see any problem. And it's a rather typical business requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *Pivot*. Unfortunately, DB2 doesn't implement the PIVOT statement (unlike Oracle). So it will not be possible to create a query that creates a dynamic number of columns.

Have a look at [Poor Man's SQL Pivot. List Questions as Columns and Answers per User in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924641/poor-mans-sql-pivot-list-questions-as-columns-and-answers-per-user-in-one-row). That's the closest you can get to.

Comment: Many thanks for the information and link ! The answer to Aaron Murphy's question (6158230) does what I require. - I've migrated the data to MySQL which has a pivot command, so the problem is solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic procedure that allows to pivot a table: https://github.com/angoca/db2tools/blob/master/pivot.sql